# one checkbox two values with specific purposes

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a project. I have one checkbox with two values. I want them to have a specific purpose. The first value is for adding all checked checkbox and the second value is for inserting to the database since its an array.

I've already solved the adding all checked checkboxes:

```
$value1 = $$row["amount"]; 
$value2 = $$row["product_id"]; 

<input type="checkbox" value="&value1,$value2" name="model[]>;
```

Comment: What’s your question..?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" value="$value1,$value2'" name="violation_list[]" onclick="findTotal()">

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: The first value is for adding all the specific amount of the product the second value is for insertion to the database. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can’t have a checkbox giving more than one value...

Comment: Ah, I see, but how to insert another input with value inside a checkbox? That can be active when it's checked.

Comment: You can’t. You’re over complicating. Just make a variable or a Boolean based on the checkbox and set the value for your second variable that way.